# What's the shortcut key or setting to not have Chrome's magnifying glass from appearing by default when opening inspector

Tags: windows, macos, google-chrome

When I open the element inspector on chrome (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) the magnifying glass automatically is selected.

Is there a setting to keep it off unless clicked or keyboard shortcut to turn it off?

Just trying to keep from having to turn it off with a mouse click every time.

Answer (score 0):

[Found the answer](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

## To open Dev Tools without inspector:

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Mac) to open the DevTools.

## To close element inspector after dev tools already open

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on Mac) to open the DevTools in Inspect Element mode, or toggle Inspect Element mode if the DevTools are already open.